# What causes the Acumatica site Installation ID to change?

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone know what are some some environment changes/events that could cause an Acumatica site installation ID to change?

I know creating a new site for an existing database will, but the question here is if i have an existing site with an installation ID that changes after some event occurs. Does anyone have a quick reference to these types of events that could cause the ID to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the full algorithm used to creation the installation ID is proprietary, I am able to confirm that the following elements will influence the generation of this ID:

- Local host name
- Unique identifier of the account name under which the app pool is running
- IIS Site name
- Exact virtual path
- Database name

Comment: awesome. this is exactly what i was looking for.